# Creating New Operator

Tags: new-operator, raku, prefix-operator

I'm trying to make ¬ a logical negation operator.

```
¬ True;

multi sub prefix:<¬> ($n) {
        return not $n;
}
```

When I run the above program, it returns this error:

> ```
> $ perl6 test.pl6  
> ===SORRY!=== Error while compiling /home/devXYZ/test.pl6 Bogus statement at /home/devXYZ/test.pl6:1
> ------> <BOL>⏏¬ True;
> expecting any of:
>     prefix
>     term
> ```

Does anyone know what the cause might be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The declaration of the new operator must appear before its usage. Changing the program to:

```
multi sub prefix:<¬> ($n) {
    return not $n;
}
say ¬ True;
```

Makes it work fine.

Perl 6 has strict one-pass parsing rules. Therefore, order matters with anything that influences the language being parsed - such as by introducing a type or a new operator.